# Is it possible to overwrite web-form-portlet portlet.properties with hook?

Tags: liferay, hook, portlet

Is it possible to overwrite web-form-portlet portlet.properties with hook in liferay portal?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can create portlet project with web-form-portlet in your IDE, change properties and then deploy web-form portlet again.

Comment: @BigT if this answers your question, please accept it

Answer (score 1):

You can only extend/change Liferay itself with a hook, not any other plugin. However, you can build your own webforms portlet, similar to a hook, with the technique documented in this [wiki article](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Plugin+to+extend+a+plugin)